# ArcGIS Pro - Arcade Attribute Rule Cumulative Calculation

Tags: arcgis

I am stuck trying to create an attribute rule/field calculation using Arcade where upstream areas are added to a downstream area called "Cumulative Area"

| NodeFrom | NodeTo | Area | CumulativeArea |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 10 | 10 |
| 2 | 3 | 5 | 15 |
| 4 | 3 | 6 | 6 |
| 4 | 3 | 6 | 6 |
| 3 | 5 | 8 | 20 |

Essentially I am thinking of the SQL equivalent of a SUM WHERE NodeTo = NodeFrom. Or an excel equivalent of [Area + SUMIF(CumulativeArea, NodeFrom, NodeTo)]

This is for QA'ing sewer calculations so please let me know if there are any tools out there that may already have this kind of functionality.

Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

I think you're just tired and need to re-evalute the tools you're already using. Other tools won't be node specific. In faster settings the area is more difficult to process at the speed you require. Try disassembly of your current tool for full copyright. You're on the right track.